# Drawing picture from pixels matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, draw

I want to draw an image from a matrix that contains color values. It look like this:

```
TEMP = zeros(100,100);

for i=1:100
    for j=1:100

        if (...)
            TEMP(i,j)=0;
        elseif (...)
            TEMP(i,j)=56;
        elseif (...)
            TEMP(i,j)=32;
        end
    end
end

image(TEMP)
```

But it only draws using this colors:

[image]

These colors have values from 0 to 66, step=2

How can I draw RGB colors using matrix? Especially I need grey color

Comment: Simple solution: `colormap gray`;)

Comment: Like that, exactly like that.

Comment: OK. But I want to draw gray, green, blue and yellow at once. That was really my question.

Comment: I added an answer to explain. If you want RGB colors, then you'll need an RGB matrix, which is not `[100 x 100]` but `[100 x 100 x 3]`. Why do you ask one thing if you want to achieve another thing?

Comment: Ok, thanks. But last question, how do i draw this matrix?

Comment: Have you tried `image` again? Or better yet, `help image`?

Comment: Already figured it out. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `colormap` to `gray` to get a BNW image:

```
TEMP = rand(100)*255;
image(TEMP)
colormap gray
```

If your colours are inverted, use `image(-TEMP)`.

Answer (score 2):

A 2D array cannot define colors on its own, one need to associate a colormap with it. Your default colormap is `jet` (from blue to red) and you can change it to `gray` for instance but with this kind of display you will always use only a subset if colors.

If you want to use any RGB color, then you need an RGB array, *i.e.* an array of dimensions n-by-m-by-3. The sub-array `A(:,:,1)` will code for red, `A(:,:,2)` for green and `A(:,:,3)` for blue. With this kind of array the command::

```
image(A);
```

should give you a true RGB display.